# Как сформировать xml файл по xsd схеме?

Tags: python, xml, xsd, задание-на-собеседовании

Есть задача с собеседования, цитирую:

> При помощи Языка программирования Pyhton сформировать файл xml согласно xsd схеме (HoldingStructure.xsd). Исходные данные содержатся в двух других xml файлах: (Person_1.xml и Person_2.xml).

Как подобное можно реализовать?
Очень хотелось бы ответ в формате кода, пусть не по конкретному случаю, но что-то аналогичное, чтобы было в качестве примера

*Уточню, на момент написания треда, собеседование уже закончилось, мне эта информация для общего развития :)*

[Задание (pdf)](https://disk.yandex.ru/i/N4jv0g_FPWHz6w)

[Схема (xsd)](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/OEw9U-AOocajAQ)

[Первый изначальный файл (xml)](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/_SehbEFbKrsmyg)

[Второй файл (xml)](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/mRh6-UGCh7S-Og)

Comment: По схеме xsd генерируются классы (структуры данных) Питона. Xml-файлы парсятся и заполняются объекты этих классов. После чего они сериализуются в результирующий xml.

Comment: Xsd на питоне те ещё пляски. Нормальное решение я так и не нашёл... Но простенькие схемы можно думаю на lxml или xmlschema собирать